# Keyboard behaving strangely in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard on my HP Laptop has started acting strangely.

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, it starts zooming out (which could indicate that the <kbd>hyphen/minus</kbd> key is being pressed).

When I press <kbd>right arrow</kbd> key, the screen rotates (which could indicate that the <kbd>alt gr</kbd> key is being pressed).

If I press <kbd>shift</kbd>, it selects/highlights the entire row in my text area/field.

I have simply no idea what has happened. I have tried reinstalling the keyboard driver, but it says that it already has the best driver installed.

I have also tried completely uninstalling the keyboard driver, but it says that the computer has to restart, but the driver is still installed when it boots again.

What can I do? Even though some of the behavior indicates that some other keys are being pressed, it still seems not to be the case since it doesn't type anything when I highlight a text area/field.

I have also tried activating the on screen keyboard to see if any keys are being pressed.

Do you have any suggestions what to do, what to check, etc?

Comment: Try opening the On Screen Keyboard and see if it shows any particular modifier key held down.

Comment: It doesn't show any keys being held down

Comment: Is [sticky keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/make-keyboard-easier-to-use#1TC=windows-7) turned on?

Comment: I've just tried plugging an external keyboard to my laptop and it works. So I guess it's a hardware problem and not some settings on the computer.

Comment: Did you restart your computer (should always be the 1st troubleshooting step)?

Comment: Yep. Many times

Comment: Did you check if there was anything like a paper clip stuck under the keys?

Comment: When did the problem start?  Was this soon after a new Windows update was installed?  It is possible your keyboard driver is not entirely compatible with a recent update.  You could try restoring the system to before any recent updates were installed.